# Can there be conflicts between HADOOP_CONF_DIR and SPARK_CONF_DIR?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, log4j2

We have a virtual machine (Redhat) with pyspark installed in a python virtual environment.

We have set HADOOP_CONF_DIR and SPARK_CONF_DIR.
HADOOP_CONF_DIR contains core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml etc. and also a log4j.properties file.
SPARK_CONF_DIR contains spark-defaults.conf and log4j2.properties file.
SPARK_HOME is set to the python virtual environment lib/python3.x/site-packages/pyspark

the application works as expected except for one single thing and I can't seem to find the root cause.

for some reason the settings of the log4j.properties file in HADOOP_CONF_DIR are applied to the root logger of the spark application. All dependencies of packages like spark, parquet, iceberg etc. are using the settings of the log4j2.properties file in SPARK_CONF_DIR.
If we remove the log4j.properties file from the HADOOP_CONF_DIR then nothing of the spark application gets logged, if we change that file, that configuration is applied to the root logger of the application.

We also deployed the application in a docker container and for these deployments we don't have the issue.
In those deployments the root logger of the spark application follows the configuration as specified by the log4j2.properties file in SPARK_CONF_DIR. We can remove the log4j.properties file in the HADOOP_CONF_DIR -> there's no impact.

So it seems that in one environment (virtual machine) the system somehow gives priority to the HADOOP_CONF_DIR to find the location of the log4j configuration file while in the other environment (dockerized) the system uses the SPARK_CONF_DIR to find the location of the log4j configuration file.

Even if we use in the spark-defaults.conf the `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/full_path_to_log4j2.properties` the system still uses the log4j.properties file in the HADOOP_CONF_DIR for its root logger.

What could be the cause for the system messing up the localization of the log4j configuration file?